# Calling click functions inside a main function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just wanted to know about any downsides to calling click functions inside a main function rather than in the `$(document).ready(function() {});`. This is what i mean

```js
function tester() {
  $('.className-1').click(function() {
    var cmtpid = $(this).attr('data-cmtpid');
    alert(cmtpid);
  });
  $('.className-2').click(function() {
    var pid = $(this).attr('data-pid');
    alert(pid);
  });
}
tester();
```

UPDATE : the `tester()` function will only be called once, this  is all mainly because I want to avoid inline html `onclick=""`

Comment: One _downside_ might be that if those elements are not present when the binding is invoked, the handlers will not fire as expected.

Comment: Not sure what you are expecting other than document.ready has a specific purpose and you are not using that purpose with a function call..... other than that, I am not sure what you are expecting as an answer.

Comment: Another _downside_ is that if you call `tester()` more than once you will get additional  `click` bindings each time you call it. Probably **not** what you want.

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with doing this, however it depends on the context in which you call `tester()`, and how many times. Without knowing that there's no way to answer this with any certainty

Comment: You can write `$(document).ready(tester);`

Comment: tester() will be called after DOM has loaded, I just want to replace all my inline html onclick with a separate function that handles all clicks to all elements that return an action when clicked while still not directly adding the click event to document.ready only the tester() call will be in the document.ready

Answer (score 1):

Since I noticed you're using jQuery. Perhaps consider adding `unbind("click")` after the selector to ensure you don't accidentally bind the click more than once causing multiple executions upon click.

Also there isn't any *REAL* downside but I would **HIGHLY** recommended putting that java-script at the very end of your html document to ensure the DOM is loaded.

Example:

```
$('.className-1').unbind("click").click(function(){

});
```

Comment: Yes thank you, tester() will be called after DOM has loaded, I just want to replace all my inline html onclick with a separate function that handles all clicks to all elements that return an action when clicked while still not directly adding the click event to document.ready only the tester() call will be in the document.ready